# Web application with photo upload on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, upload, photos

I must write a web application that allows people to upload photos (that are taken with a web cam) inside a Facebook album. I read about Graph API, but I don't understand if I can use these API only to create a Facebook application (accessible only from Facebook) or if it is possible to use it in my personal website, accesible from a url (like www.myapplication.com).

I read about social plugin that allow to add Like button or Send button on website, but there are no social plugin to upload photos on profile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an application first (see here : https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Applications can work through facebook canvas but also allow you to add functions to your website via Javascript/PHP/... SDK.

Here is a PHP demo to upload photos to a facebook profile :
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498

You can also upload a photo to facebook by sending an URL :
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/